# Differentiation of definite integral.

Tags: integration

I want to answer the following question:
Is it true that\begin{equation}F(x)=\int \limits _{x_0}^xf(g(t))\,dt\implies \frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(g(x))?\tag{1}\end{equation}

What I know is that\begin{equation}F(x)=\int \limits _{x_0}^xf(t)\,dt\implies \frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(x)\tag{2}\end{equation}is true.

Coming back to the question, let $f(g(x))=h(x)$ and using Eq. (2), we get Eq. (1).

Am I right? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: yes, (2) implies (1)